# Do we really need Blog module in Drupal 7 (and 8)?

Tags: nodes, 8

In Drupal 7, the Blog module do not have any option to change the URL. Because I want a different URL, I build blogs without the Blog module. For blog pages, I make it using Views and theme modification. I find it more flexible that way than using the Blog module. Nothing less except more flexible and extensible because it using generic approach.

I stumbled upon the [Blog](http://drupal.org/project/blog) module for Drupal 8. I just wonder why the Blog module still exist. Why are there people still building it, if we can building it with the available modules and theming?

Is there anything good I missed in the Blog module?

Comment: This question isn't really answerable. The answer is either yes or no, depending on whether you need a pre-prepared blog module or not. The fact that you can build a similar interface with views etc. is completely incidental. You can build a taxonomy using node hierarchy and content types but that doesn't negate the usefulness of the taxonomy module, for example.

Comment: FYI as well, that blog module is actually the Drupal 5/6/7 core blog module, just [moved into contrib](http://drupal.org/node/233301).  It's one of the more useless modules that has been removed from D8 core (along with Poll if I remember correctly).

Comment: I do remember correctly - [Make core maintainable](http://drupal.org/node/1255674) just in case anyone's interested:

Comment: Wow seven downvotes for a question that clearly demonstrates that thought has gone into it.  Unlike a lot of open-ended questions, a good answer could be formulated to explain both the strengths and features of the Blog module.

Comment: I actually means strengths and weaknesses...

Comment: @MPD the problem with the question is that it seems a rant disguised as a question. The fact the OP prefers not to use the Blog module doesn't mean there aren't users who want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the Blog module exists for people who used it with Drupal 5 and 6, and are upgrading sites.

Personally, I never found the blog module of much uses.  Typically, clients want something different about their blog, so I just roll my own with custom content types, [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and custom blocks (as needed).

Comment: Out of curiosity, does downvoter consider this "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"?

Comment: Yes blog is not that much usefull, but it will help to fresher or who want to develop a basic side or to a people who are coming from wordpress or any other simple cms.